# Typescript 2.x : converting a generic JSON to a model using reflection/meta-data

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

We have an api that returns data in the form of JSON with property names in lower case and property values as strings. Due to reasons outside our control we can't change this API. Our front typescript classes have camel case property names and properties have actual types. We have lots of code where we convert the backend data to front end types as shown below.

```
//------------------------------------------------------
//Front End Model
//------------------------------------------------------
export class Account {
    depositFrequency: number;
    name: string;
    id: number;
}

//------------------------------------------------------
//Model for backend JSON
//------------------------------------------------------
export class AccountFromApi {
    depositfrequency: string;
    name: string;
    id: string;
}

//------------------------------------------------------
// code in service that does the conversion
//------------------------------------------------------
getAccount(): Promise<Account> {
    const queryString = blah blah.....
    return this.wsp.get(queryString).then((account: AccountFromApi) =>
        this.formatAccount(account));
}

private formatAccount(account: AccountFromApi): Account {

    let depositFrequency = parseFloat(account.depositfrequency),
        name = (account.name),
        id = parseInt(account.id);
    return {
        depositFrequency: !isNaN(depositFrequency) ? id : null,
        name: name,
        id: !isNaN(id) ? id : null
    };
}
```

This is a lot of redundant code everywhere. We have one FromAPI(AccountFromAPI) class and one Format function(formatAccount) for each model we have. I am wondering if we can use some sort of reflection and write a common function (instead of formatAccount) that will take a generic Type and convert the json to our front end model. Something like...

```
    private formatToType<T>(someJSON: any): T {

    //get all properties of type T and also their type
    //convert property names to lower case.
    //see if those properties exist in json , do type conversion 
    //return object of type T
}

//It will be called like 
getAccounts: Promise<Account> {
    const queryString = blah blah.....
    return this.wsp.get(queryString).then((account: any) =>
        this.formatToType<Account>(account));
}
```

Would love your input on how to code the formatToType method....

Comment: Not sure where the question is but I think your approach is great

Comment: @Eeks33 i am not sure how i can write the formatToType. Unable to figure this out in typescript.